# Android Layout_Weight not working properly in a TableLayout?

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-tablelayout, android-layout-weight

I created this interface such that, the **top most row** of the table layout has 3 equally distributed buttons using layout_weight. But this is what I end up with:

[image]

And this is my code:

```
      <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_rel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ECECEC"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/blurImage"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5dip" >

                        <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/btnHeartLike"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:src="@drawable/selector" />

                        <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/btnShare"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:src="@drawable/share39" />

                        <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/btnProductComment"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:src="@drawable/comment_icon" />
                    </TableRow>
```

I didn't add the rest of the code since it's long and irrelevant (I think?). Let me know if you need the rest as well but I think the problem is with the layout it is in? What do you think is wrong?

Comment: relative layout does not need orientation i guess. only linear layout needs it to define whether its vertical or horizontal. Also since you are using only 3 imagebuttons why do you use a table layout and dont use a horizontal linear layout and then make the layout_width = 1 and that will give you the desired effect.

Comment: If I dont use the Table Layout the image buttons get displaced everywhere and not in a perfect row and also I have more rows below it which I didnt post on stackoverflow. Did you mean, make my linear layout horizontal? cos I already have a vertical linear layout @KostasMatrix

Comment: yes exactly. look the @kamran answer below and add horizontal orientation to his answer

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the width to 0 instead of having `wrap_content`:  `android:layout_width="0.0dip"`

And check the [following link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html) for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

why you are using `TableRow`. you can create it using  `linearlayout`

use the following code

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

the another way

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TableRow

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Button" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Button" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Button" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: No I need the table layout sir :) there's other items below this and if I dont use a table layout they are getting displaced everywhere as a mess. Isnt there a way to use a table layout and still use layout weight on the imagebuttons?

Comment: This looks good but the same problem persists :( I think it's because I have multiple rows